# How do i invert every odd letter in a string?

Tags: python

So basically I have to make a code that inverts every odd letter of a string.
I got a fair way, but couldn't figure out how to put the string back together properly.

So the output should be 'hlleo', but instead i get 'hloe'. How do i fix this?
Input is hello
Expected output is hlleo
Output is hloe

```
word = 'hello'
output = ''
value = -1
word1 = word[0::2]
word2 = word[1::2]
word2 = word2[::-1]
print(word2)
print(word1)
for letter in word2:
    value += 2
    output = word1[:value] + letter + word1[value:]
    print(output)
print('Correct output should be "hlleo"')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "invert"?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "invert" but you should work out the algorithm with a pen and paper first I think.

Comment: @chepner The program should put every odd letter in the spot on the other side of the word/sentence. So 'stackoverflow' should become 'sOaFkEvOrClTw'

Comment: @WouterB still very unclear what you are asking, just type in what your `input` is and what your `expected output` is

Comment: @user1767754 I edited the question. It says those things now.

Comment: I am not familiar with python, but you could do something like:
1. Create two seperate arrays from the original by looping through the original word, one character at a time, and writing each even character to the first array, and each odd character to the 2nd array.
2. Reverse the order of the characters in the 2nd array (the odd one)
3. Merge the two arrays back together again by looping through the even one, and appending each odd character (which are now in reversed order)
You could then build upon that to make it more efficient (for example perhaps reverse looping, using 1 array etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the string into a `list` and use slice assignment and `join` it back together:

```
w = 'abcdef'
l = list(w)
l[1::2] = l[1::2][::-1]
w2 = ''.join(l)
# 'afcdeb'
```

Comment: I do have a question tho: Is the way i started my code simply impossible to complete, or is there a way to fix my problem?

Comment: Amit Tripathi's answer is more along the lines that you started.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
In [6]: word = 'hello'

In [7]: dorw = list(reversed(word))

In [8]: new_word = ''

In [9]: for i in range(len(word)):
   ...:     w = word[i]
   ...:     if i % 2 != 0:
   ...:         w = dorw[i]
   ...:     new_word += w
   ...:

In [10]: new_word
Out[10]: 'hlleo'
```

Based on index `i` a word is taken either from the real "word" or the reversed version of it.

Comment: This approach is most consistent with the attempt made in the code provided by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner.

```
inv_word = "".join([word[i] if i%2==0 else word[len(word)-(i+1)] for i in range(len(word))])
```

The logic here is that we build a new list of characters by iterating over the word. If the index is even (`i%2==0`), then we use the corresponding index in the word. Otherwise, we use the inverted character which is found at index `len(word)-(i+1)`.

At the end, join the list together with `"".join()` to make it a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
def revodd(s):
    l = list(s)
    l[1::2] = reversed(l[1::2])
    return "".join(l)
```

Convert to a list of strings (because lists are mutable and strings aren't), set a slice of the odd indices to a reversed version of itself, and `join` the list back into a string.  I see @schwobaseggl has done the reverse with a slice, but I think using `reversed` is much more readable.

Test cases:

```
In [23]: revodd("0123456789")
Out[23]: '0927456381'

In [24]: revodd("012345678")
Out[24]: '072543618'

In [25]: revodd("hello")
Out[25]: 'hlleo'
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your code snippet to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I have misunderstood your question, this can only 'work properly' with odd length strings so that the odd indexed characters are all swapping with other odd indexed characters.

```
def invert_odds(string):

    # Get reverse of string
    reverse = string[::-1]

    new_string = ""

    # Make new string with chars from either original or reversed
    # strings depending on index
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            new_string += string[i]
        else:
            new_string += reverse[i]

    return new_string
```